# How to convert road lane coordinates to tensors in Python?

Tags: python, pandas, pytorch, computer-vision, torchvision

I am trying to develop a Lane Detector using PyTorch. Basically, I'm reading the video frame by frame using `cv2`, then finding edges using `Canny Edge Detector` and then I'm using average lane algorithm to get lane's coordinates.

These coordinates look like `[[x1, y1, x2, y2], [x3, y3, x4, y4]]` and my .csv dataset is looks like:

```
image-0.jpg,"[[449, 576, 353, 600], [696, 576, 722, 600]]"
image-1.jpg,"[[165, 951, 468, 1654], [465, 654, 416, 654]]"
...
```

*(I'm saving images frame by frame from the video to specify the road lanes because I will train my model on these images and coordinates. That's why my database has names of every frame. image-0.jpg, image-1.jpg, image-2, etc.)

`*(([x1, y1, x2, y2] is left road lane, [x3, y3, x4, y4] is right road lane))`

But in the `__getitem__` method of my dataset class, I'm getting this error:

```
    y_label = torch.tensor(int(self.annotations.iloc[index, 1]))
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '[[449, 576, 353, 600], [696, 576, 722, 600]]'
```

How can I fix this code? I want these coordinates to be readable by PyTorch so I can train my model on these coordinates and road images that I save. I tried to convert coordinates' list to tensor list but I couldn't do that.

My full database code:

```
import os
import pandas as pd
import torch
from torch.utils.data import Dataset
from torchvision import transforms
from skimage import io

class RoadLanesDataset(Dataset):

    def __init__(self, csv_file, root_dir, transform=None):
        self.annotations = pd.read_csv(csv_file)
        self.root_dir = root_dir
        self.transform = transform

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.annotations)

    def __getitem__(self, index):
        img_path = os.path.join(self.root_dir, self.annotations.iloc[index, 0])
        image = io.imread(img_path)
        y_label = torch.tensor(int(self.annotations.iloc[index, 1]))

        if self.transform:
            image = self.transform(image)

        return (image, y_label)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it is because you are trying to convert a list of lists to an int.

Try making the tensor like this with the dtype `torch.long`.

```
y_label = torch.tensor(self.annotations.iloc[index, 1], dtype=torch.long)
```